# Can I convert a physical non-bootable sata volume to a VHD image for mounting in a VM as 2nd volume?

Tags: virtualization, vhd

I'm converting physical machines in the office to virtual machines using Disk2vhd, and it doesn't list the second physical hard drive that is in one of the physical machines. Does that mean I cannot create an image for mounting inside the VM? Or am I missing some crucial info here?

[edit] currently trying out this answer https://serverfault.com/a/28575/209257 as it does list the disk

[edit2] WinImage created an image successfully, once I find a drive that is big enough to move it to I'll be able to test and let you know of the outcome. Sorry for asking a question before trying this out. Mods; you may close the question?

Comment: Korijn,  you're probably best off putting the solution in as an answer and accepting it to close out the question.